# I am getting non-sensical results by migration my laravel migrations. It says my table's are not exist

Tags: php, laravel, database-migration

I didn't know what to put as a title. Here is the story basically:

1. We have copied all the project files from our development machines to the server.
2. We have dumped the database (an `.sql` file) from our development machines and installed the whole database to the server machine. (In this stage we didn't make any migration on the server machine.)
3. Three months has passed since the last work. We cloned the repository and the dumped database file to our development machines again.

Now we get the same error when we try to apply migrations. First situation:

1. There are all the tables in the database. We create a migration via `php artisan make:migration some_name`
2. When we apply this migration via `php artisan migrate` it fails. Here is the error message:
   [image]
3. The above exception is thrown when all the tables in the database. We have deleted all the tables (or all the tables except `migrations`) we got this error message when we applied migrations via `php artisan migrate`:[image]

I would really like to know what is going on in here. Before we deleted the tables the output of `php artisan migrate:status` is this:

```
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Ran? | Migration                                             |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
| Y    | 2014_10_12_000000_create_users_table                  |
| Y    | 2014_10_12_100000_create_password_resets_table        |
| Y    | 2016_01_06_094947_create_announcements_table          |
| Y    | 2016_02_22_075425_create_menuheadings_table           |
| Y    | 2016_02_22_075913_create_menuitems_table              |
| Y    | 2016_02_24_071923_create_publication_databases_table  |
| Y    | 2016_02_24_075752_create_contact_table                |
| Y    | 2016_02_24_095726_create_personnels_table             |
| Y    | 2016_02_24_140554_add_image_field_to_announcement     |
| Y    | 2016_02_26_075730_create_slider_table                 |
| Y    | 2016_02_26_104627_create_publicaton_databases_table   |
| Y    | 2016_02_26_105429_create_databasees_categories_table  |
| Y    | 2016_02_26_135506_add_publication_database_published  |
| Y    | 2016_03_02_072620_create_replaceable_pages_table      |
| Y    | 2016_03_02_072702_create_page_images_table            |
| Y    | 2016_03_02_090219_create_general_pages_table          |
| Y    | 2016_03_02_123206_delete_column_page_images           |
| Y    | 2016_03_02_123227_create_column_image_url             |
| Y    | 2016_03_04_074143_create_wish_information_table       |
| Y    | 2016_03_04_074557_create_wish_books_table             |
| Y    | 2016_03_04_074632_create_wish_article_table           |
| Y    | 2016_03_04_074727_create_wish_ill_table               |
| Y    | 2016_03_11_071731_rename_image_url_personnels         |
| Y    | 2016_03_11_072543_rename_personnels_image_url         |
| Y    | 2016_03_16_104742_add_published_expiration_table      |
| Y    | 2016_03_16_125254_add_weight_column_personnels        |
| Y    | 2016_03_23_091637_create_database_istatistics_table   |
| Y    | 2016_03_24_084610_create_library_use_statistics_table |
| N    | 2016_05_16_111816_create_rating_questions_table       |
| N    | 2016_05_17_124800_create_rating_results_table         |
| N    | 2016_05_23_093005_create_english_menuheadings         |
| N    | 2016_05_23_093214_create_english_menuitems            |
| N    | 2016_05_23_093409_create_eng_general_pages            |
| N    | 2016_05_23_093531_create_english_replaceable_pages    |
| N    | 2016_10_17_084839_create_some_table                   |
+------+-------------------------------------------------------+
```

Comment: The error messages are pretty clear. It looks like you didn't do migrations the right way. Two options: either install the database from .sql file and insert all migration filenames into migrations table, or fix your migration files and do a clean schema install.

Comment: @jakubwrona Could you explain the details about how to do that? Fixing my migration files and doing cleaning schema install.

Comment: or you can also use this to generate migrations from an existing database: https://github.com/Xethron/migrations-generator